# Decrement/increment for qty and the value field

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a cart page with the ability to use the add or minus buttons to decrement or increment the value of the input but the eventlisteners don't seem to be working and I have tried many different solutions online for this and get it to work properly.

```
{% extends "base.min.html" %}

{% block body_block %}

{% load static %}


<div class='container'>
    <a class='back-link' href="/"> Back to Catalog</a>
    <h1 class='cart-h1'>Cart </h1>
    <div class='cart'>
        <div class='requests'>
            <div class='request'>
                <img src='https://developers.elementor.com/docs/assets/img/elementor-placeholder-image.png' alt='request image'>
                <div class='request-info'>
                    <p class='request-name'>Request: {{ requestName }}</p>
                    <p class='request-details'>Details: {{ requestDetails }}</p>
                    <p class='request-qty'>Qty: {{ requestQty }}
                        <div class='qty-container'>
                        <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' id='plus' field='quantity' />
                        <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' id='inputQty' />
                        <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' id='minus' field='quantity' />
                        </div>
                    </p>    
                    <p class='qty-remove'></p>
                    <span class='remove'>Remove</span>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</br>

<div class='hidden-container'>

    <p>Checkout Confirmation #: {{confirmNum}}</p>

</div>




<script type="module" src="{% static '\js\supplyshop\pageload\RequestManagementLoad.min.js'  %} " type ="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

```
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('#plus')
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('#minus')
const inputQty = document.querySelector('#inputQty')


// increment/decrement value on input field
// add eventlisteners on +/- buttons to update the value field


plusBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    inputQty.value = parseInt(inputQty.value) + 1

})

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (inputQty.value <= 0) {
        inputQty.value = 0
    }

    inputQty.value = parseInt(inputQty.value) - 1
})
```

I tried using incrementing/decrementing the value of the input field which holds the quantity value. I've also tried using the onclick function in html and making a function that does the same thing in that but I may be going about it the wrong way as nothing is working properly. The behavior I am expecting is to click the plus or minus button and the number in the middle (input field) will increase by one or decrease by one if the add/minus button is clicked. I also want to make sure the value can't go below 0.

- 1 -

Comment: Hi , your code seems to work for me . Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g93paqfr/) fiddle .

Answer (score 0):

check with this:

> minusBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
> e.preventDefault()
>
> ```
> if (inputQty.value <= 0) {
>     inputQty.value = 0
> }else{
>   inputQty.value = parseInt(inputQty.value) - 1
> }
> ```
>
> })